# SQL GROUP BY with FILTER IN SELECT

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, pivot

If I have the following sample data:

```
╔══════════════╦══════════════════╦════════════╦═══════╗
║    Client    ║      con_id      ║ mat1_07_03 ║ Ccode ║
╠══════════════╬══════════════════╬════════════╬═══════╣
║ Clients Name ║ C13109BBFD511534 ║ $1,062.00  ║ NOFL  ║
║ Clients Name ║ C11AC9BBF74D6882 ║ $879.73    ║ NOFL  ║
║ Clients Name ║ C12A69BBF1ACB578 ║ $2,790.29  ║ NOFA  ║
║ Clients Name ║ C12A69BBF1ACB578 ║ $912.00    ║ NOFL  ║
║ Clients Name ║ C6B0CA1A767C9744 ║ $2,180.11  ║ NOFL  ║
║ Clients Name ║ C11AC9BBF74D6882 ║ $878.67    ║ NOFA  ║
║ Clients Name ║ C13B79BBF4F1F450 ║ $300.00    ║ NOFL  ║
║ Clients Name ║ C12A69BBF1ACB578 ║ $1,790.67  ║ NOFL  ║
║ Clients Name ║ CA6869E2FE38A449 ║ $240.00    ║ NOFA  ║
║ Clients Name ║ C46439FB0D847140 ║ $3,392.66  ║ NOFL  ║
║ Clients Name ║ C12A69BBF1ACB578 ║ $1,791.73  ║ NOFA  ║
║ Clients Name ║ C13B49BBF12ED236 ║ $0.00      ║ NOFL  ║
║ Clients Name ║ C12A69BBF1ACB578 ║ $879.73    ║ NOFL  ║
╚══════════════╩══════════════════╩════════════╩═══════╝
```

And Apply the following query:

```
SELECT 
     [Client]=MAX(m.Client)
    ,[CaseCount]=COUNT(m.con_id)
    ,[AmtInDispute]=CONVERT(char, SUM(Convert(money, m.mat1_07_03)), 101)
FROM lntmu11.matter m
GROUP BY m.con_id
ORDER BY COUNT(m.Client) DESC
```

How can I further group the `Ccode` Column to get the `COUNT` of how many rows are either
`NOFA` or `NOFL`

My desired output would appear as:

```
╔══════════╦═══════════╦═══════════════╦═══════════════╦══════════════╗
║  Client  ║ CaseCount ║ NOFACaseTotal ║ NOFLCaseTotal ║ AmtInDispute ║
╠══════════╬═══════════╬═══════════════╬═══════════════╬══════════════╣
║ Client A ║      3548 ║          2000 ║          1548 ║ 5,658,307.60 ║
║ Client B ║      3366 ║           100 ║          3266 ║ 2,885,649.48 ║
║ Client C ║      3014 ║           800 ║          2214 ║ 2,851,507.13 ║
║ Client D ║      2340 ║           340 ║          2000 ║ 3,467,207.12 ║
╚══════════╩═══════════╩═══════════════╩═══════════════╩══════════════╝
```

Comment: +1 for taking the time to format your question so nicely.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT m.Client, CaseCount = COUNT(m.con_id),
       CONVERT(varchar(255), SUM(Convert(money, m.mat1_07_03)), 101) as AmtInDispute
       sum(case when cCode = 'NOFA' then 1 else 0 end) as NOFACaseTotal,
       sum(case when cCode = 'NOFL' then 1 else 0 end) as NOFLCaseTotal,
FROM lntmu11.matter m
GROUP BY m.client
ORDER BY COUNT(m.Client) DESC;
```

Note:  when doing conversions to a character, always include the length (in T-SQL).

Answer (score 2):

You can use conditional aggregation to get the other 2 columns.  Using an aggregate function with a CASE expression to count the `Ccode` values that you want for each of the columns.

```
SELECT 
     [Client]=MAX(m.Client)
    ,[CaseCount]=COUNT(m.con_id)
    ,NOFACaseTotal = sum(case when m.Ccode = 'NOFA' then 1 else 0 end)
    ,NOFLCaseTotal = sum(case when m.Ccode = 'NOFL' then 1 else 0 end)
    ,[AmtInDispute]=CONVERT(char(50), SUM(Convert(money, m.mat1_07_03)), 101)
FROM lntmu11.matter m
GROUP BY m.con_id
ORDER BY COUNT(m.Client) DESC;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/32a78/2).

Answer (score 1):

Like Gordon and Bluefeet have said Conditional Aggregation FTW!

```
SELECT 
     [Client]=MAX(m.Client)
    ,[CaseCount]=COUNT(m.con_id)
    ,[AmtInDispute]=CONVERT(char, SUM(Convert(money, m.mat1_07_03)), 101)
    ,[NOFACaseTotal]=sum(case when Ccode = 'NOFA' then 1 else 0 end)
    ,[NOFLCaseTotal]=sum(case when Ccode = 'NOFL' then 1 else 0 end)
FROM lntmu11.matter m
GROUP BY m.con_id
ORDER BY COUNT(m.Client) DESC
```